Is it possible to show a WinUi3 MenuFlyout without a Window or other UIElement?
I am relatively new to WinUi3. My goal is to create a simple bridge for using native components inside a e.g. Java project so that you can create and show a MenuFlyout at a specific position on screen.
I tired passing null as UIElement on menuFlyout.ShowAt(null, new Point(0, 0)); but that results in an error.
Here what I tried:
MenuFlyout menuFlyout = new();
MenuFlyoutItem menuItem = new(){ Text = "Test Exit" };
menuItem.Click += (sender, e) => { m_window.Close(); };
menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuItem);
menuFlyout.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = false;
menuFlyout.ShowAt(null, new Point(0, 0));


The MenuFlyout needs an element to provide a UI surface. You can use a 0x0 window, say.

Could you try that out? I am not able to. It won't get smaller than the window controls.

Forgot to mention: Use ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = false to allow the MenuFlyout to extend beyond the window bounds.

It's easy to change the size of the window with WinUIEx NuGet package:
MainWindow.xaml
<ex:WindowEx
    xmlns:ex="using:WinUIEx"
    x:Class="WinUIApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIApp3"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        x:Name="RootGrid"
        Loaded="Grid_Loaded" />

</ex:WindowEx>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Foundation;
using WinUIEx;

namespace WinUIApp3;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : WindowEx
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IsTitleBarVisible = false;
        MinWidth = 0;
        MinHeight = 0;
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuFlyout menuFlyout = new();
        MenuFlyoutItem menuItem = new() { Text = "Test Exit" };
        menuItem.Click += (sender, e) => { this.Close(); };
        menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuItem);
        menuFlyout.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = false;
        menuFlyout.ShowAt(RootGrid, new Point(0, 0));
    }
}

